# R call to C code faster than c++ function call to C code?

Tags: c++, c, r, performance

for my project I have a R program that calls many times a C function, implemented using `#include <R.h>` and `#include <Rdefines.h>`. Since I want to speed as much as possible the whole algorithm, I coded the R program directly in C++, so to remove the layer of translation between C and R. 
I called the previously coded C function from C++, as a regular function. I was able to do the translation and to obtain the same output.

Looking at run time I found out that the R execution is faster than the C++ one (2m 10 sec vs 2m 50 sec). To find out where the "problem" was I have used two profilers: gprof and Valgrind, that both report a runtime usage of 99% of the time by the C external function. This gives me no explanation about this difference in run time of 30%, while 99% of the time is spent on executing the same C code. For the integration of C++ and C I have tried both lo link the C object file, and to link all the .o of C creating a single library (libExternal.a). Do you have any suggestion of which could be the reason of this difference?

I have attached a part of the valgrind report. The external C function is underlined.[image]

Thank you!

Here the result of perf stat -d on the C++ program:
[image]
Here the result of perf stat -d on the R program:
[image]

I want to remind you that 99% of the time is spent in the C function, which is the same for both. In the C++ code I just create the objects before passing to the function, so data should be side by side in the memory. Thank you for your help

Comment: Include your code please.

Comment: or include *some* code that also shows the problem. or even counterexample code. Doing this might even be enough for you to figure out the problem yourself...

Comment: I cannot add code since it is too long and it would not help. What I can say to explain what the algorithm does is that I am iterating over a data matrix taken in input, and depending on the index I dinamically create some arrays to contain some results, and I pass the arrays and the data matrix to the c function, that evaluates some measures on them, returning an array. R does the same, but the objects that passes are R Objects, that are translated to c arrays by the c code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, memory layout/memory access might play a decisive role here. Basically, if CPU spend 99% time in function X(), it doesn't mean it is really doing anything. Most likely CPU is waiting for data to be delivered, and one implementation is waiting less (or more) than the other one.

I would advice to check using `perf` suite, cache hits and misses etc.

Link: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/hpc-prof-events.html

Comment: CPU is not waiting data inside the function. C++ is passing a matrix and some arrays as pointers, and these are used by the function. You are right that it could be a cache/ram problem, but I cannot understand since array are just created when passed, and their position in ram should be one near the other.

Comment: `CPU is not waiting data inside the function`  - wll, CPU is pretty much ALWAYS waiting for data, that's the nature of the modern beasts, this is why we have multi-level caches and hierarchy of access times. The only question is for how long they wait. Did you try `perf stat`?

Comment: I added perf stat -d results on both cases. Thank you for your help

Comment: However many calls to stat gave quite different results

Comment: @Nadir Very interesting! So in first case it is actually a better and faster code, code with more IPC - 2.36 instructions/cycle vs 2.01 instructions/cycle. But! In first case there is just a LOT more instructions to execute - ~1320 trln vs ~860 trln. This is why it is slower. I would venture it is due to different optimization levels, -O1 vs -O3 ? No inlining vs aggressive inlining?

Comment: @Nadir Basically, if I rescale execution time by number of instruction, first case should finish in 115 seconds or so...

Comment: You are right! The problem was that they gave me non optimized .o files for the C code! Sorry for this! Now I have reached 70 seconds with only 226trln of cycles! Thank you a lot!!